# Link text thicker than normal text

Tags: html, css

How can I make the text below thicker while keeping the links as they are?

```
li
{
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height:28px;
    font-weight:thick 
}

a:link 
{
color:#3399CC; 
}

...

<div id="left_column" >
    <ul>
    <li><a href="a.html">Im happy as I am</a>&nbsp-&nbspI want to be less thick</li>
    <li><a href="b.html">Im also happy as I am</a>&nbsp-&nbspI also want to be less thick</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: [Not seeing your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bwV7v/), in Chromium/Ubuntu 11.04 (note that I did correct your HTML entities, the non-breaking spaces *should* be `&nbsp;`, the semi-colon isn't optional.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want the links to be bolded and the text to be less thick (ie not-bolded)

Look at the code below, same as yours except I defined `font-weight:normal;` in the `<li>` and `font-weight:700;` in your `<a>` tags. [Here's the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/dsanto/vnHKR/).

Try this in your code:

```
li
{
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height:28px;
    font-weight:normal; 
}

a:link 
{
font-weight: 700;
color:#3399CC;
}


<div id="left_column" >
    <ul>
    <li><a href="a.html">Im happy as I am</a>&nbsp-&nbspI want to be less thick</li>
    <li><a href="b.html">Im also happy as I am</a>&nbsp-&nbspI also want to be less thick</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/gYFxQ/) has an answer your query.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
    color:#3399CC;
    font-size: 10px;
}
li {
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height:28px;
    font-weight:thick 
}
ol>li>a{
    color:#3399CC; 
    font-size: 10px;
}

</style>
<body>
<div id="left_column" >
    <ol>
    <li><a href="a.html">Im happy as I am</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;I want to be less thick</li>
    <li><a href="b.html">Im also happy as I am</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;I also want to be less thick</li>
    </ol>    
    hree
</div>
</body>
</html>
```